# Custom NodeTree and NodeCustomGroup and bpy.ops.node.tree_path_parent()

Tags: python, pynodes

I've done a fair amount of custom PyNode tree scripting for Sverchok, but one thing remains a bit nebulous and i'm hoping someone can shed some light.

The Material node trees have this Group feature which turns the background green and enables an operator on the header to call `bpy.ops.node.tree_path_parent()` to go to the parent node tree.

[image]

The poll / execute code for `bpy.ops.node.tree_path_parent()` is [(...full code link)](https://github.com/dfelinto/blender/blob/3068ea34e414e7af6d20af7ab92c69cbd9a33414/release/scripts/startup/bl_operators/node.py#L286-L290)

```
@classmethod
def poll(cls, context):
    space = context.space_data
    # needs active node editor and a tree
    return (space.type == 'NODE_EDITOR' and len(space.path) > 1)

def execute(self, context):
    space = context.space_data
    space.path.pop()
    return {'FINISHED'}
```

For a NodeGroup of ShaderNodeTree `space.path` becomes a collection of 2 paths.

```
<bpy_collection[2], SpaceNodeEditorPath>
--- <bpy_struct, ShaderNodeTree("Shader Nodetree")>
--- <bpy_struct, ShaderNodeTree("NodeGroup")>
```

My simple attempt at declaring a NodeCustomGroup has some superficial success. 
My question is how / where can I set the `space.path` so there's something to `.pop()`, -- somewhere in the `init` of the custom node?

excerpt [full code here](https://github.com/nortikin/sverchok/blob/group_experiment/nodes/basic_data/group_exp.py):

```
class SvGroupNodeExp(bpy.types.NodeCustomGroup, SverchCustomTreeNode):
    bl_idname = 'SvGroupNodeExp'
    bl_label = 'Group Exp'
    bl_icon = 'OUTLINER_OB_EMPTY'

    group_name = StringProperty()

    def init(self, context):

        self.node_tree = bpy.data.node_groups.new('nooobgroup', 'SverchCustomTreeType')
        self.group_name = self.node_tree.name
        # self.node_tree.parent = self
        # space = context.space_data
        nodes = self.node_tree.nodes

        inputnode = nodes.new('SvGroupInputsNode')
        outputnode = nodes.new('SvGroupOutputsNode')
        inputnode.location = (-300, 0)
        outputnode.location = (300, 0)
```

Comment: Wouldn't you do that in `bpy.ops.node.group_edit()`?

Comment: maybe [i'm not reading this right](https://github.com/dfelinto/blender/blob/3068ea34e414e7af6d20af7ab92c69cbd9a33414/source/blender/editors/space_node/node_group.c#L86-L103), but perhaps group_edit() is limited to standard node trees? -- i've implemented an operator to switch active node tree, and am tempted to also implement a `back_to_parent` operator..

Comment: None of the standard group operators work in custom node trees, we need to implement our own create/edit/ungroup operators. That would be the place to add/pop to `space.path`. Not sure we can use the existing menu entries but we can use the same shortcuts to run the custom operators.

Comment: Thanks @sambler this confirms my suspicion.. pitty it's not so elegant to replace an operator in the node tree header..

Comment: see [object_nodes ../group_nodes.py](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/object_nodes/release/scripts/nodes/group_nodes.py) by PyNodes' creator for a Python implementation of group_nodes

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure how useful this is to people ([see a sverchok branch which implements this](https://github.com/nortikin/sverchok/tree/group_experiment)). I'll provide this as answer to my question, because that's what it does -- whether or not this allows for a functional custom node_tree group implementation is still up in the air.

---

It seems the way to get the `node.tree_path_parent` to poll `True` is to repopulate the `context.space_data.path` with the parent tree at index 0 and the new group node (a tree under the hood) at index 1.

```
def group_make(self, new_group_name):
    self.node_tree = bpy.data.node_groups.new(new_group_name, 'SverchCustomTreeType')
    self.group_name = self.node_tree.name

    nodes = self.node_tree.nodes
    inputnode = nodes.new('SvGroupInputsNode')
    outputnode = nodes.new('SvGroupOutputsNode')
    inputnode.location = (-300, 0)
    outputnode.location = (300, 0)
    return self.node_tree

class SvGroupEdit(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "node.sv_group_edit"
    bl_label = "edits an sv group"

    group_name = StringProperty()

    def execute(self, context):
        node = context.node
        ng = bpy.data.node_groups

        group_node = ng.get(self.group_name)
        if not group_node:
            group_node = group_make(node, new_group_name=self.group_name)

        bpy.ops.node.sv_switch_layout(layout_name=self.group_name)
        # context.space_data.node_tree = ng[self.group_name]  # does the same

        # by switching, space_data is now different
        parent_tree_name = node.id_data.name
        path = context.space_data.path
        path.clear()
        path.append(ng[parent_tree_name]) # below the green opacity layer
        path.append(ng[self.group_name])  # top level

        return {"FINISHED"}
```

However, when hitting the `back` button (`tree_path_parent`) the active node_tree isn't set. Why? I suspect it's due to using `.clear()` instead of `.pop()` and some loss of information. This means we need to roll our own version of `tree_path_parent`, to switch the node_tree and then set the `context.space_data.node_tree` to the desired parent tree.

Something like:

```
class SvTreePathParent(bpy.types.Operator):
    '''Go to parent node tree'''
    bl_idname = "node.sv_tree_path_parent"
    bl_label = "Parent Sv Node Tree"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        space = context.space_data
        return space.type == 'NODE_EDITOR' and len(space.path) > 1

    def execute(self, context):
        space = context.space_data
        space.path.pop()
        context.space_data.node_tree = space.path[0].node_tree
        return {'FINISHED'}
```

Bottom left in the screenshot i prepended the operator button for `node.sv_tree_path_parent`.

[image]

Comment: have there been any improvements to the Custom Node Group since this was posted?