# convert sverchok script node to script node lite

Tags: scripting, node-editor, sverchok

After updating blender I cant use a **script node** (SN) from someone else that I was using before. Now sverchok has **script node lite** (SNL). I dont know what I need to change for it to work, and cant find documentation on the changes either. (at the time of writing there's no documentation on the existence of SNL, [just SN](https://sverchok.readthedocs.io/en/stable/nodes/generator/scripted_intro.html))

Can anyone point me to information about this?

[edit]

Somewhat related questions:

[Is there a way to use Sverchok's ScriptNode without defining in_sockets?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/88641/is-there-a-way-to-use-sverchoks-scriptnode-without-defining-in-sockets) (links to [SNL doc](https://github.com/nortikin/sverchok/issues/942) in a github issue)

[Custom NodeTree and NodeCustomGroup and bpy.ops.node.tree_path_parent()](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58614/custom-nodetree-and-nodecustomgroup-and-bpy-ops-node-tree-path-parent)

[Has anyone started a project similar to Grasshopper (Rhino) for blender?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/485/has-anyone-started-a-project-similar-to-grasshopper-rhino-for-blender/6546#6546)

[How do I build an object using Python and predetermined coordinates?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/69824/how-do-i-build-an-object-using-python-and-predetermined-coordinates/69844#69844)

[Can custom nodes be written for the compositor?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57138/can-custom-nodes-be-written-for-the-compositor/57187#57187)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found conversions other users have performed, and diffed the two versions to check the changes they made. They only seem to change the syntax of the input/output in such a way that `sv_main` is no longer used:

- every item in the lists `in_sockets` and `out_sockets` is now defined at the start inside bracketed (`"""`) comments with the commands `in` and `out`
- after the `in` / `out` command the variable name is given, followed by the variable type
- the `in` variables also get a `d` default value, which was in `sv_main` before, and an `n` value of `1` or `2`
- if the default value is `[]` then `n=1` otherwise `n=2` (I dont know the meaning of this)
- all code in `sv_main` is just executed at the end of the script and the `def` and `return` lines are just deleted

For instance

```
in_sockets = [
    ['s', 'maximum branches', npoints],
    ['s', 'branch length', dist],
    ['s', 'minimum distance', min_dist],
    ['s', 'maximum distance', max_dist],
    ['s', 'tip radius', tip_radius], 
    ['v', 'tropism', trop],
    ['v', 'End Vertices',  verts_in],
    ['v', 'Start Vertices', verts_start]
]


def sv_main(npoints=100 , dist=0.05, min_dist=0.05, max_dist=2.0, tip_radius=0.01, trop=[], verts_in=[], verts_start=[]):
    out_sockets = [
        ['v', 'Vertices', [verts_out]],
        ['s', 'Edges', [edges_out]],
        ['s', 'Branch radii', [rad_out]],
        ['s', 'Ends mask', [ends_out]],
        ['m', 'Leaf matrices', mats_out],
    ]
    #some code
return in_sockets, out_sockets
```

Is converted to

```
"""
in npoints s d=100 n=2
in dist s d=0.05 n=2
in min_dist s d=0.05 n=2
in max_dist s d=2.0 n=2
in tip_radius s d=0.01 n=2
in tropism v d=[] n=1
in verts_in v d=[] n=1
in verts_start v d=[] n=1
out verts_out v 
out edges_out s 
out rad_out s
out ends_out s
out leaf_mats m
"""
#some code
```

I took these code snippets from a sverchok script by [elfnor](https://elfnor.com/sverchok-tree-generator.html), so thanks to her for the example!